# SQL results not updating on form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

I am updating a mysql based comment system into PDO, however I have encountered a strange problem. It works completely fine other than the fact that I have to reload the page for the new comment to show. This didn't happen before. Here is the PHP for the submit part:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
  $name = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
  $cmt = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $time = time();
  $cmtpostquery = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO commentsdev (post_id,ip,name,content,date) VALUES (:view, :ip, :name, :cmt, :time)");
  $cmtexec = array(":view" => $view, ":ip" => $ip, ":name" => $name, ":cmt" => $cmt, ":time" => $time);

  if((empty($name)) || (empty($cmt))) {
    echo '<div style="color: red; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'.MISSING_FIELD.'</div>';
  } 
  else {

    if(!$resp->is_valid) {
      echo '<div style="color: red; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'.CAPTCHA_WRONG.'</div>';
    } 
    else {
      $cmtpostquery->execute($cmtexec);
      if($cmtpostquery->errorCode() == 0)
        echo '<div style="color: green; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'.CMT_SUCCESS.'</div>';
      else
        echo '<div style="color: red; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'.SQL_ERROR.'</div>';
    }
  } 
}
```

And here is the HTML for the form:

```
<form method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="name">Username:</label></td>
      <td><input name="name" id="name" maxlength="64"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="comment">Comment:</label></td>
      <td><textarea name="comment" id="comment" style="width: 500px; height: 120px;" maxlength="1500"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="captcha">Verification:</label></td>
      <td>'.recaptcha_get_html($publickey).'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Post Comment" name="submitted"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Looking forward for your guidance ..

Comment: Use a header to redirect after successful query.

Comment: If I do that, I don't see the "Comment Successful" message, and it's not really that flexible.

Comment: @user3611314 Then try a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/" />`

Comment: use ajax then @user3611314

Comment: I'd really rather not. If it worked with mysql then it must be able to work with PDO.

Comment: The only thing I can tell that could cause this are missing braces `{}` for `if($cmtpostquery->errorCode() == 0)
        echo '<div style="color: green; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'.CMT_SUCCESS.'</div>';
      else`

Comment: I fixed it... by moving a variable down a few lines. I didn't intend to fix it that way; I was just reorganizing it. Case closed then! It was `$cmtdata = $cmtviewquery->fetchAll();` that I moved.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.